# How to move files in Amazon S3 buckets using AWS JAVA SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I know I can do it by copying the file to new location and deleting it from current location. But I want to know, is there an built-in api/sdk for moving files from one folder to another in a bucket of AWS? or any other efficient way to move files?

Comment: Not in the AWS SDK at the time of writing but the AWS S3 CLI has a mv operation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/mv.html) but it probably implements the copy/delete method.

Answer (score 0):

`s3Services.moveObject()` can be used.

Comment: Can you please add a reference or an example? Thank you!

Comment: https://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/api/org/jets3t/service/StorageService.html#moveObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.jets3t.service.model.StorageObject-boolean-

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I wasn't clear in my message, sorry. Let me explain better: first, it would be better to [edit] the answer and add all the relevant info there, instead of here in the comments. The reason is that not everybody reads comments, and they could be deleted anyway. Answers, instead, are guaranteed to be kept. Moreover, a link isn't considered enough for the site guidelines, because one day it might become invalid and then it would be useless. So, could you please add at least a summary of what can be found there? Thank you, and sorry for not being clear the first time!